# How to marshal arbitrary structures and unions between C# and C?

Tags: c#, c, interop, marshalling

I have a C program compiled to a DLL which I load into C# (using kernel32.dll LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary). Using GetProcAddress I can get a pointer to some data in memory, and I want to convert this data to an equivalent structure in C#.

My first idea was to create structs in C# that mapped directly to the C structs (using the `StructLayout` and `MarshalAs` attributes), and then just use the `Marshal` class (in `System.Runtime.InteropServices`). This works well for "simpler" structs, but does not work for multi-dimensional arrays and unions of arrays.

The data structures in C looks like the following (for example):

```c
struct MyStruct 
{
    union MyUnion my_data[16][16];
}
union MyUnion
{
    uint32_t ints[2];
    uint8_t bytes[8];
}
```

I.e, it contains arbitrarily nested structs and unions, and multidimensional arrays of these.

Is there a built in way in C# to handle marshalling of these types of data structures?

---

Edit:

My requirements are:

- The C# unions must work the same way as the C ones, i.e writing to the `bytes` field should also change the `ints` field (afaik, using explicit struct layout you can only make unions of built in value types in C#). (This is more a C# issue than a marshalling issue)
- The C# structures must be marshallable to and from C/C++

As Selvin noted in the comments it's possible to flatten multi-dimensional arrays into a single dimension, and then access by [x + y*16]. However I prefer if the original dimensions were preserved, and the method of accessing is the same as in C.

My answer below does what I want, but since marshalling between C# and C++ is so common it feels like there should be a simpler way to achieve that result.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note that the wording "*What's the best way to...*" can make your question get closed soon because a direct answer is likely to be more based on opinions than facts. I edited your question because in the overall look, you do not even ask for that.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that `my_data[256]` should work with acces like `my_data[x + y*16]`

Comment: There are [several good examples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-classes-structures-and-unions).

Comment: Have a look at [Marshaling Classes, Structures, and Unions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-classes-structures-and-unions). There you find some samples. Another way, I prefer especially for complex c structures and/or calling multiple functions of a naitive C dll is creating a [C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019) wrapper dll.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. My biggest issue is marshalling unions of arrays, which the built in marshaller really does not like. For the union in my example above, writing to the `bytes` field should also change the values in the `ints` field. Maybe that's a question of its own?

As @Selvin says it's possible to flatten out multidimensional arrays to a single array. I have tried it and it works OK, but I would prefer using the same method of accessing values as is used in the C structs, for consistency.

Comment: have you considered a c++/cli layer so you can do conversions etc without relying on the marshaller?

Comment: @JonasH I haven't looked at doing anything on the C++ side. Do you have an example for how that could look? It is possible to do something there, however I would prefer if I can perform operations on the data using the same modes of access (ie index into arrays) as used on the C++ side. So in the end I still want to model the same data in C# using structures/classes and operate on those in the same way.

Comment: @William Forsdal there should some c++/cli example if you google around, I have no specific one I would recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to create a wrapper class around the raw data `byte[]`, with accessors that imitate the structure of the underlying data.

For example, for a simple structure in C:

```
struct MySimpleStruct
{
    uint32_t my_ints[16];
}
```

I create a wrapper:

```cs
public class MySimpleStruct
{

    private byte[] _underlying;
    public UintAccessor[] MyInts { get; }

    public MySimpleStruct(byte[] data) 
    {
        _underlying = data;
        MyInts = new UintAccessor[16];
        // for-loop to initialize each accessor with the right index
    }
}
public class UintAccessor
{
    public uint Value 
    {
        get => BitConverter.ToUint32(_underlying, _idx);
        set => BitConverter.GetBytes(value).CopyTo(_underlying, _idx);
    }
    public UintAccessor(byte[] data, int index) { /* ... */ }
}
```

and the wrapper can be used like so

```cs
var myStruct = new MySimpleStruct(theData);
myStruct.MyInts[5].Value = 123;
```

These wrapper classes can become quite complex, however we automatically generate the C structures and we will generate these C# wrappers at the same time, so the complexity is only an issue when generating the code.